# A bag contains 15 balls of the same shape and size. Of these, 9 balls are blue...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bag contains 15 balls of the same shape and size. Of these, 9 balls are blue, and the remaining 6
balls are red. Suppose 7 balls are removed randomly (without replacement) from the bag, in such
a way that any 7 balls originally in the bag is equally likely to be the 7 balls that are removed from
the bag. What is the probability that the number of red balls removed from the bag is exactly 4?

I tried to figure out that the Sample space: drawing 2 balls. So we have a total of 15 balls and we can draw any 7 so the total possibilities are 15C7. Don't know how to proceed further

Comment: The next thing to consider is the number of ways the 7 balls can consist of 4 red and 3 blue.

Comment: how should i do that

Answer (score 1):

There are $15\choose 7$ ways to make the selections.  Of these, there are ${9\choose 3}\cdot {6\choose 4}$ ways to choose exactly $4$ red balls.   So...?

Comment: I am not able to understand can you please tell the final solution thanks

Comment: Just divide the number of successes by the total possible outcomes.

Comment: so 9C3*6C4/15C7 is the solution

Comment: Yes.  That's it.